# Fedora Linux VM has garbled audio when using Chromium but works fine with Firefox running

Tags: fedora, audio, firefox, chrome

I am completely lost with this one, I just don't know where the issue could be.

I have a Fedora 37 VM I run on my laptop via VMware Workstation 17 Pro (on Windows 11). While the machine boots up no problem and it's usable I am having some strange issues with keyboard lag and garbled sound. However to make things even more bizarre the issues with the sound resolve themselves with a certain mix of applications are running.

My test I have done so far is the following;
Boot Fedora VM and run Chromium. Play random YouTube video. Audio is garbled and running very slow. If I try to do the "Test speakers" in KDE I also get garbled and slow audio when it says "Front Left, Front Right".

Next I tried Firefox as a fallback. Did the same thing, played a random YouTube video. This time however the audio plays perfectly. No stuttering on the video, no issues with audio quality. Strangely enough if I leave Firefox running the background doing nothing then run Chromium the audio is Chromium works perfectly fine. However, if I close Firefox the audio instantly goes garbled and slows down like it did before.

I am 100% lost with this one. What would cause the machine to run fine with Firefox running but the minute Firefox closes the audio quality is degraded to a degree of not being usable.